# Why is this invalid JSON?

Tags: jquery, json

I am sending some data from an server back to a page. It looks like valid JSON to me, yet, it is being caught/handled by the error handler in my jQuery.ajax() call.

This is the error message displayed:

```
Error: Invalid JSON: ({"id":"#settingsResult","payload":"<form id=\"pwd_change_frm\" action=\"post\">\n    <div>\n        <div>\n            <div><\/div>\n            <div><label for=\"changepwd_password\">New Password<\/label><\/div>\n            <div><input type=\"password\" name=\"changepwd[password]\" title=\"Enter new password\" style=\"width:258px;\" id=\"changepwd_password\" \/><\/div>\n        <\/div>\n        <div class=\"spacer\">&nbsp;<\/div>\n        <div>\n            <div><\/div>\n            <div><label for=\"changepwd_password_confirm\">Confirm New Password<\/label><\/div>\n            <div><input type=\"password\" name=\"changepwd[password_confirm]\" title=\"Retype new password)\" style=\"width:258px;\" id=\"changepwd_password_confirm\" \/><\/div>\n        <\/div>\n        <div class=\"spacer\"><\/div>\n        <div><img id=\"pwd_chg_btn\" class=\"submit_btn\" src=\"\/images\/button_submit.gif\" alt=\"Button_submit\" \/><\/div>\n    <\/div>\n    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"changepwd[_csrf_token]\" value=\"1b7f3529797245c0fc43c3ddf5ade30d\" id=\"changepwd__csrf_token\" \/><\/form>\n<div class=\"spacer\"><\/div>"})
```

As an aside, FF Firebug correctly parses the returned data and displays ot correctly - which is why I dont understand why jQuery can't seem to handle it.

here is the bit of code that makes the call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/some_url?id='+this.id,
  timeout: 2000,
  success: function(result){ jQuery(result.id).html(result.payload); },
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ alert('Error: '+ thrownError); }
});
```

Comment: http://www.jsonlint.com/ validates the JSON (I pasted it without the parenthesis)

Comment: using jq 1.5 or 1.5.1 ? 1.5 had some bugs maybe this is it? They did major overhaul of ajax module so I wouldn't be suriprised. Json validator says json is ok so *shrug*.

Comment: You must have resolved it since you accepted an answer, but using jQuery's `$.parseJSON()` it failed for me even without the `()`. I was however able to get it to parse if I removed all `/n`, and replaced all `\"` with `\'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the surrounding '()', remove it and its valid json.

Answer (score 7):

Probably useless to answer at this point, but I just thought I'd note that the issue does somehow seem to be with `$.parseJSON()`.

If I remove all occurrences of `\n`, and replace all occurrences of `\"` with `\'`, it works.

Alternatively, if I double escape them, it works.

```
\\n
\\"
```

...which would make sense since I believe jQuery simply does an `eval()` (or effectively the same thing), so I guess escaping the `"` is terminating the string and escaping the `\n` is introducing a newline character where it would be invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Since everything else appears to be valid, the problem is likely that you are including `(` and `)` in the data.

Answer (score 1):

The error also appears when you use jquery validate (version 1.7). You can check: http://datatables.net/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=3993&page=1#Item_16

I also upgraded to jquery 1.5.1 and i had the same issue. After i updated jquery validate (from here: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation) the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual JSON that is being passed?  The string in the error message:

```
{"id":"#settingsResult",
 "payload":"\n \n \n <\/div>\n New Password<\/label><\/div>\n <\/div>\n <\/div>\n  <\/div>\n \n <\/div>\n Confirm New Password<\/label><\/div>\n <\/div>\n <\/div>\n <\/div>\n <\/div>\n <\/div>\n <\/form>\n<\/div>"}
```

is valid according to [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/).  Are you including the parens?

**Update after Question Changed**

Is it possible that `<\/div>` is somehow confusing things?  This isn't valid HTML so I don't know what `jQuery(result.id).html(result.payload)` is going to do with it.

Comment: From a js/json perspective its just a string, so for this error it doesn't matter that its not valid html.

Answer (score 0):

jquery requires that you supply "dataType: json" unless you supply the proper content type in your serverside code like "header('Content-type: application/json');"

Answer (score -1):

According to json.org

> JSON can be either an array or an object
>
> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins
>   with { (left brace) and ends with }
>
> [object structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLhOg.gif)
>
> An array is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with [
>   (left bracket) and ends with ]
>
> [array structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLLrn.gif)

So JSON should start with either '{' or '[' and it can't start with '('

Also you use following online validator like debugjson.com to always check errors of your JSON input.